# ADO.net issues with code behind giving me a prob

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am currently trying to save some data from a form to my sql database. I am using ADO.net. I have created connection, model and it all seems fine but it s returning the following errors:

> Error 7   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Nuage4School.ClassroomCreate'
>   to 'Nuage4School.UploadFile'  D:\Visual Studio
>   2012\Labs\Nuage4School\Nuage4School\RegisteredAccess\Addclassroom.aspx.cs 39  36  Nuage4School

and

> Error 4   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(Nuage4School.ClassroomCreate)'
>   has some invalid arguments    D:\Visual Studio
>   2012\Labs\Nuage4School\Nuage4School\RegisteredAccess\UploadDocument.aspx.cs   37  12  Nuage4School

My form is as follow:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Add a classgroup</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Classgroup_Name">Classgroup Name</asp:Label><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox6" Width="250px" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Classgroup_Name"
                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The field is required." />
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Subject">Subject</asp:Label><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Width="250px" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Subject"
                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The field is required." />
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label runat="server"  AssociatedControlID="Number_of_Students">Number Of Students</asp:Label><asp:Dropdownlist runat="server" ID="Dropdownlist1"><asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>32</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>33</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>34</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>36</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>37</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>38</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>39</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>41</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>42</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>43</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>44</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>46</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>47</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>48</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>49</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                                           </asp:Dropdownlist>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Number_of_Students"
                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The field is required." />
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label  runat="server"  AssociatedControlID="Start_Date">Start Date</asp:Label><asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="calendar1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="190px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" Width="350px" >
                <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
                <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
                <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" />
                <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            </asp:Calendar>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label runat="server"   AssociatedControlID="Finish_Date">End Date</asp:Label><asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="calendar2" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="190px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" Width="350px" >
                <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
                <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
                <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" />
                <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            </asp:Calendar>
        </li>

        <li>
            <asp:Label runat="server"  AssociatedControlID="Access_Key">Enter Access Key</asp:Label><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox4" Width="250px" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator  runat="server" ControlToValidate="Access_Key"
                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The Access Key is required." />
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Access_Key">Re-enter Access Key</asp:Label><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox5" Width="250px" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator  runat="server" ControlToValidate="Access_Key"
                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="Please Re-enter Access key." />
        </li>

    </ol>
<fieldset>
```

and my code behind:

```
private Nuage4SchoolDatabaseEntities1 Nuage1 = new Nuage4SchoolDatabaseEntities1();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get info 
    //set info in the new page - set attribute values to html tag
    Button1.Attributes["text"] = "go";
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassroomCreate Create = new ClassroomCreate();


    Create.Teacher_id = Page.User.Identity.Name;
    Create.Classgroup_Name = TextBox6.Text;
    Create.Subject = TextBox1.Text;
    Create.Number_of_Students = Dropdownlist1.Text;
    Create.Start_Date = calendar1.VisibleDate;
    Create.Finish_Date = calendar2.VisibleDate;
    Create.Access_Key = TextBox4.Text;

    Nuage1.UploadFiles.Add(Create);
    Nuage1.SaveChanges();
```

`Nuage1.UploadFiles.Add(Create);` seems to be the problem. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass an instance of `ClassroomCreate` to the `Nuage1.UploadFiles.Add()` method.

The error is telling you it cannot convert `Nuage4School.ClassroomCreate` to `Nuage4School.UploadFile`.

Looks to me like you might be passing the wrong object to the `Add()` method. It expects an instance of `UploadFile`, not `ClassroomCreate`.